# Check if password contains only letters, numbers, some extra characters

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to check whether a password contains only letters, numbers and only these characters:

```
~ _ & * % @ $
```

I am using a regular expression as follows. But it is not working as expected:

```
var checkPassWordCharacters=/[a-zA-Z0-9~_&*%@$]$/;
if(checkPassWordCharacters.test(password)){
    //do Something
}
```

What am I doing wrong, and how can I fix it?

Comment: missing `^` start of string anchor and a `+` quantifier for your char class

Comment: *"What is going wrong in it?"* You are only checking whether the string **ends** with one of those characters.

Comment: Will you accept a password that is just one character like `_`

Comment: Not an answer, but I have to ask: why are you limiting the characters people can use in their password?

Comment: also, just in case you don't know, it's okay to do some pre-validation with javascript to save on server calls, but make sure you validate server-side as well, because it's laughably easy to circumvent javascript validation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regex should be `/^[a-zA-Z0-9~_&*%@$]+$/` to match a string of the following format:

- Beginning of the string
- Any number of specified characters (in the `[]` brackets) (excluding 0 characters)
- End of the string

Your regex would have matched this:

- Any amount of any character
- One of the specified characters (only 1 character)
- End of the string

Answer (score 0):

Your regex should be `/^[a-zA-Z0-9~_&*%@$]*$/`,
because according to your requirement, empty password is allowed. The star (`*`) here allows you to accept an empty password as well.